# Functional equation $f(xf(y)) = x^2y^a$

Tags: functional-equations

> If $f:(0, \infty)\to(0, \infty)$ is an into function satisfying $f(xf(y)) = x^2y^a, (a\in\mathbb R)$, then find the value of $a$ and the number of solutions of $2f(x) = e^x$.

My approach:

$f(x(f(y))) = x^2 y^a$

$y=x$

$f(x(f(x))) = x^2 x^a$

$f(xy) = x^2 x^a$, (as $f(x) = y$)

$y = 1$

$f(x) = x^a x^2$

This seems to be incorrect? Where have I gone wrong? How do I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You're making the same errors [this poster did](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3822236): questions should have some context, should be properly typeset, and should include your own thoughts.

Comment: Now I have edited this

Comment: Jee! It's exactly the same question as linked above!

Comment: Please see this tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Integrand ok but please don’t remove this

Comment: @Integrand I have edited this again please check

Comment: This question has more to it than the supposed duplicate. Not only to find $f$, but also to find the number of solutions to $2f(x)=e^x$. None of the answers address the number of solutions.

Answer (score 2):

We have $f: (0, \infty)\rightarrow (0, \infty)$ such that $f(x f(y)) = x^2 y^a~\forall x, y\in(0, \infty)$.

For $x\leftarrow 1$:

1. $f(f(y)) = y^a~\forall y\in(0, \infty)$

For $y\leftarrow f(y)$:

2. $f(x f(f(y))) = x^2 f(y)^a~\forall x, y\in(0, \infty)$

By replacing **1.** in **2.** we have

3. $f(x y^a) = x^2 f(y)^a~\forall x, y\in(0, \infty)$

In **3.**, for $y\leftarrow 1$, we have

4. $f(x) = x^2 f(1)^a~\forall x\in(0, \infty)$

In **4.**, for $x\leftarrow 1$, we have

5. $f(1) = f(1)^a$

As $f(1)\neq 0$, we shall have $f(1)^{1-a} = 1$, therefore $f(1) = 1$ or $a = 1$:

If $a = 1$, then, replacing **3.** in the original equation, we have

$\begin{aligned}
f(x f(y)) &= x^2 y^a&\forall x, y\in(0, \infty)&\implies\\
f(x y^2 f(1)) &= x^2 y&\forall x, y\in(0, \infty)&\implies\\
x^2 y^4 f(1)^3 &= x^2 y&\forall x, y\in(0, \infty)&\implies\\
f(1)^3 &= y^{-3}&\forall y\in(0, \infty)&\implies\\
f(1) &= y^{-1}&\forall y\in(0, \infty)
\end{aligned}$

which is clearly absurd, therefore $f(1) = 1$, so, by **4.**, we have $f(x) = x^2~\forall x\in(0, \infty)$, so

$$f(xf(y)) = x^2 y^a~\forall x, y\in(0, \infty)\implies x^2 y^4 = x^2 y^a~\forall x, y\in(0, \infty)$$

therefore $a = 4$.

Comment: Why can’t f(1)=1/y

Comment: @MichaelJackson because $1/y$ assumes many different values, but $f(1)$ must be a constant.